# AES Encryption in Swift cannot decrypt in C#

Tags: c#, swift, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm currently trying to call a web service with basic authorization and I've spent 3 days on it. But, still stuck on the way to encrypt by swift code. 
I already have had the encrypt function working fine by C# but I'm looking for a swift one. Any help, please!

This is my swift code to encrypt a string with Key and Initialization Vector (IV) generated from UUID. Project included CryptoSwift

```
func getCredential() -> String {

    let secretKey = "RlBUX09SVF9Nb2JpbGVfXw=="
    let sessionClaim = "this is the secret session claim"

    // Create IV
    let uuid = SwiftyUUID.Version4UUID()

    let plainData = NSData(bytes: uuid as [UInt8], length: uuid.count)//uuidString.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
    // Get IV String
    let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    var encryptedClaimString: String = try! sessionClaim.encrypt(cipher: AES(key: Array(secretKey.utf8), iv: uuid, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()))

    //var encryptedClaimString = try! sessionClaim.aesEncrypt( key: secretKey, iv: uuidString)
    encryptedClaimString += ":"
    encryptedClaimString += base64String

    let utf8String = encryptedClaimString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let credentials = utf8String?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    return credentials!;
}
```

After do some dissect, I got exactly key and iv but the function cannot decrypt to get the sessionClaim as original input. this is the C# decrypt function

```
public static string Decrypt(byte[] encrypted, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        string value = null;

        // Create an Rijndael object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.IV = iv;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        value = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Might be padding issue?